# Imported data missing from report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, reports-api, custom-reports

We have a report that a customer built on their production org. It reports on an object and also pulls data from a related list on that object. The data that has been created since their production environment went live displays fine. But any data migrated from their old system does not. It pulls the name from the main object, but the related list data is all blank.

However if I go look at any of the records they appear to be identical as far as fields populated etc. I checked and all the fields on the object are visible to the correct users. There is obviously some issue with the fields from the related list object being visible or read, but I can't think of what it could be.

Also I did notice that the missing records had a parent record that was owned by a user who had a different role than the records that were visible (and in some cases it was a queue which was never the case with the visible records). However I had our customer change one of the missing record to the same user as a valid record and it did not change the visibility.

So I am really stuck?

Comment: Check OWD and how you are exposing the visibility either by sharing rules or apex managed sharing or manual sharing

Answer (score 0):

Record visibility in reporting takes in so many aspects of the instance that it's hard to debug without being hands-on. Some important things to check would be:

- What are the Org-Wide Defaults for the parent and child objects, if the child is not controlled by parent?
- Is it possible that the related list object is Master-Detail with a completely different object?
- What are the owners of all of the records involved and what are their roles?
- Who is the running user for the report and what is *their* role?
- Where are the running user and the record owners relative to one another in the hierarchy?
- Are there any sharing rules active?
- Is any Apex Managed Sharing in place?

Typically, I would assume that this issue stems from migrated data being owned by an integration user whose data isn't shared with the user running the report. I am not convinced that the experiment you describe completely eliminates this possibility. Adding more information about the objects and the role hierarchy might be helpful.